# How does one calculate the centroid of an equilateral triangle using integration

Tags: calculus

Edit: The vertices are $(0,0)$, $(1, 0)$, $(1/2,  \sqrt{3}/2)$. Please confirm. Confirmed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume the equilateral triangle of side one with a vertex at the origin.  Clearly, the $x$-centroid is $\bar{x} = 1/2$ by symmetry, so we need only find $\bar{y}$.  The expression for the centroid of a region $R$ is

$$\bar{y} = \frac{\displaystyle\iint_R dA \, y}{\displaystyle\iint_R dA}$$

It's all about picking the bounds of the integral.  In this case, you can see that the triangle is bounded by the lines $x=y/\sqrt{3}$ and $x=1-y/\sqrt{3}$.  I chose $x$ as a function of $y$ rather than vice-versa because I can do the calculation with a single integral rather than break up into two.  The integrals are then

$$\bar{y} = \frac{\displaystyle\int_0^{\sqrt{3}/2} dy \, y \: \displaystyle\int_{y/\sqrt{3}}^{1-y/\sqrt{3}} dx}{\displaystyle\int_0^{\sqrt{3}/2} dy \: \displaystyle\int_{y/\sqrt{3}}^{1-y/\sqrt{3}} dx}$$

I leave it you to do these integrals out.  The result I get is

$$\bar{y} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{6}$$

Comment: Shouldn't we get sqrt(3)/4 since centroids should stay the same when flipped on axes of symmetry?

Comment: By your reckoning, the centroid is halfway up the triangle.  Does that make sense?  Most of the "weight" of the triangle is toward the bottom.

Comment: I have no idea how you got the four integrals on the fraction. Where does that come from? Idk how to do double integrals; this is calc 2.

Comment: You work from right to left.  The integrals over $x$ are trivial (just the top - the bottom limit).  That will leave you with single integrals over $y$ that involve at worst quadratics, which I assume you can do.

Comment: Yes, I can do them. I think I was trying something similar to what you did but I didn't put in terms of y. I was having great difficulty breaking up the integrals. Thanks!!

Comment: Your welcome.  If you found a solution useful, please remember to accept it.

Comment: Those integrals just give y = y I think

Comment: Uhhhh...no.  You should get, for the denominator,$$\int_0^{\sqrt{3}/2} dy \, (1-2 y/\sqrt{3})$$ Perhaps you are not used to the $dy$ being first.  It is how I write integrals.

Comment: Oh... I just don't know how to do double integrals like that.

Comment: I didn't know that they got combined

Comment: Are those separate integrals? I'm not really sure what's going on. I don't know how you derived the initial thing

Comment: I got it. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you insist to find it by integration, there is a method (though, for the beginning, the best if you draw the triangle on a paper and find the middle point right away..)

We want the *average* of all coordinates $(x,y)$ that lie within the triangle, that would give the center. The average can be calculated by integral, divided by the whole area, and it is also possible to do it coordinatewise. So we can get
$$\bar x=\frac{\int_{x=0}^1\int_0^?x\,dydx}{{\rm Area}(\Delta)} \quad \quad
\bar y=\frac{\int_{x=0}^1\int_0^?y\,dydx}{{\rm Area}(\Delta)}\,.
$$
You have to split the integrals for $x=0...1/2$ and $x=1/2...1$ and calculate the equations of the sides of the triangle to get the upper limit for $y$ for a given $x$.